# Scraping links (within grid) from HTML source code - Using R (preferred) or Python

Tags: python, html, r

Checked several posts in detail before posting as a new question. Hope this is not a duplicate!

Heads up from asker: I don't know much about HTML and dare say average knowledge on R.

I have an HTML source code and I need to extract links from it using R (preferred) or maybe Python.

**EDIT : 28/07/17**

The links I am looking for is in a nested structure of

As in;

```html
<body class="browserclass_chrome"> ==$0

   <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="./objectDetails.aspx?... 
   id="aspnetForm">

      <div id="content">

         <div id="contentMain">

            <div id="contentMainContent">

               <div id="tabbed_folder_content"> == $0

                  <div id="wholeSlidesGrid" class=folderContentGrid active-grid" style> == $0

                     <div id="pxl-ag-grid" style="height:100%; width: 100%;" class="ag-material">

                        <a href="https://etc.etc.aspx?id=XXXXX&type=r" tabindex="-1">P_xxxxxx
                        </a>
 
                     </div>

                  </div>

               </div>

            </div>

         </div>

      </div>
```

I need to extract the link designated at the end of the code above. And there are several of these links under the "div id="tabbed_folder_content".

I have installed `XML`, `RCurl`, `rvest` ( `read_html()` and `html_nodes()` ) from R language and `bs4.BeautifulSoup()` from Python.

My limited knowledge suggests that, I was unable to extract the links because they are not in the main-page but rather in a grid. (?) Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the code snippet that you tried for extracting the link? There might be something wrong with the selector you used. I recommend you use [SelectorGadget](http://selectorgadget.com/) to help you choose the right element selector

Comment: There seems to be no relation to javascript here

Comment: I installed SelectorGadget and it seems useful. The link I am looking for is in "div a" if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `R`'s `rvest` this should be simple enough. Based on the limited example you posted, this should work:

```
library(rvest)

read_html(text) %>%
  html_nodes('#tabbed_folder_content') %>%
  html_nodes('a') %>%
  html_attr('href')
#> [1] "https://etc.etc.aspx?id=XXXXX&type=r"
#> [2] "https://etc.etc.aspx?id=YYYYY&type=r"
```

With:

```
text <- '<div id="tabbed_folder_content"> == $0
  <div id="wholeSlidesGrid" class=folderContentGrid active-grid" style> == $0
    <div id="pxl-ag-grid" style="height:100%; width: 100%;" class="ag-material">
        <a href="https://etc.etc.aspx?id=XXXXX&type=r" tabindex="-1">" P_xxxxxx
        </a>
        <a href="https://etc.etc.aspx?id=YYYYY&type=r" tabindex="-1">" P_xxxxxx
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>'
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I get 'character(0)' as a result. I think this is happening because of the assignment of object "text". Might have mislead you. Please see to the updated question

Comment: The updated question is incomplete, the html structure is not well formed (`div`s should be closed and the `href` attribute is missing the `=`). 
The point of my answer still stand, you can use `html_nodes` to target the node you are interested in ( [SelectorGadget](http://selectorgadget.com/) may help you here) and then extract the link using `html_attr('href')`

Comment: Thank you for the input. Really appreciate it, I was able to use the SelectorGadget. The code above works fine but it turns out I need to login to the page in which I am trying to extract the links from. Which is why I am still couldn't scrape the links I wanted. But I feel this question is answered properly. So, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer by GGamba, but I myself prefer to scrape using readLines function and doing it manually via regex. That way, you can be very specific in what URL's you're looking to pull in case there are other URL's in those nodes. Plus I've never had any luck with Rvest myself haha.

```
text <- '<div id="tabbed_folder_content"> == $0
  <div id="wholeSlidesGrid" class=folderContentGrid active-grid" style> == $0
<div id="pxl-ag-grid" style="height:100%; width: 100%;" class="ag-material">
<a href="https://etc.etc.aspx?id=XXXXX&type=r" tabindex="-1">" P_xxxxxx
</a>
<a href="https://etc.etc.aspx?id=YYYYY&type=r" tabindex="-1">" P_xxxxxx
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>'

write.csv(text, 'text.txt', row.names = FALSE)
```

You can put the url or html object into the readLines functions

```
text2 <- readLines('text.txt')
```

Use grep and Regex here to identify the lines to pull.

```
grep('.*a href=\"\".*\"\"\\s*tabindex=.*', text2, value = TRUE) %>% 
    gsub('.*a href=\"\"(.*)\"\"\\s*tabindex=.*', '\\1', .)
```

Or this REGEX on the website format yields the same results

```
grep('.*etc\\.etc\\.aspx.*', text2, value = TRUE) %>% 
    gsub('.*a href=\"\"(.*)\"\"\\s*tabindex=.*', '\\1', .)
```

This can be especially useful if you can only identify the lines directly above what you are trying to pull by using grep and value = FALSE, which generates the index for the line.

For example:

```
index <- grep('<div id=\"\"pxl-ag-grid\"\" style=\"\"height:100%; width: 100%;\"\" class=\"\"ag-material\"\">', text2, value = FALSE)

text2[index + 1]
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I get 'character(0)' as a result. I think this is happening because of the assignment of object "text". Might have mislead you. Please see to the updated question

Comment: Did you input the text, write is out as a text file, then readLines on that text file? If so, can you put the output of text2 here to see what it looks like? 
For example:
 [5] "<a href=\"\"https://etc.etc.aspx?id=XXXXX&type=r\"\" tabindex=\"\"-1\"\">\"\" P_xxxxxx"        
 [6] "</a>" 
You may need to adjust the REGEX to find the correct line and extract out the correct info.